# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined when requesting data from db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am very new to back end development, so I am watching a tutorial. In the tutorial, mlabs is used, but Mongo Atlas seems to work differently. I am trying to display my posts using a get request, but am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at C:\Users\reaga\Desktop\Projects\fullstack-crud\server\routes\api\posts.js:10:26
```

posts.js

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const router = express.Router();

// Get post
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
    res.send(await posts.find({}).toArray());
});
// Add post

// Delete post

async function loadPostsCollection() {
    // Adding connection string to var
    const uri = 'mongodb+srv://nova:nova123@cluster0.deckb.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

    await client.connect(err => {
        client.db('Project 0').collection('posts');
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You don't return anything from `loadPostsCollection`. Also, set the connection in a method calling everytime you call `/` is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you! I won't be leaving the connection in a method; just trying it out for now!